# How to set a single modifier key as a shortcut in openbox?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, arch-linux, openbox

I want to have my super key start `dmenu`.
I set it as a keyboard shortcut in my `rc.xml`:

```
<keybind key="0x85">
      <action name="Execute">
        <command>dmenu_run</command>
      </action>
</keybind>
```

I tried specifying it as `W`, `W-`, and in with its key code (`0x85`). `W` responds to pressing the letter `w`, `W-` does nothing, and `0x85` triggers `dmenu` immediately on the KeyPress event instead of waiting for KeyRelease. So other key combos that use super as a modifier will trigger `dmenu` instead.

How can tell openbox that I only want the shortcut to trigger when the super key is pressed *and released* on it's own without any other keypresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work by using [xcape](https://github.com/alols/xcape) ([packaged in the AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/xcape-git/)).

From it's man page:

> xcape allows a modifier key to be used as another key when it is pressed and released on its own.

In short, I assigned super to a dummy shortcut (<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>[image: Linux key] Super</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>) with

```
xcape -e 'Super_L=Control_L|Shift_L|Alt_L|Super_L|D'
```

Note that you'll have to run this each time you reboot, so you may want to put it in your `~/.config/openbox/autostart` script or something.

This dummy shortcut is picked up by openbox with an entry in `rc.xml`:

```
<keybind key="C-A-S-W-d">
      <action name="Execute">
          <command>dmenu_run</command>
      </action>
</keybind>
```

---

*I also wrote a slightly more detailed answer about this [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/214956/86821)*.